# Is it possible to take cluster database backup using MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, backup, cluster-computing, workbench

Using MySQL Workbench, is it possible to take cluster database backup ?

Answer (score 0):

For standard master-slave MySQL cluster setup, "cluster backup" is backup of the master. 
And yes, it's possible to do it with Workbench.

Comment: Do you have any link to do the cluster backup ?

Comment: Yes i read you answer.When comes to cluster backup we used to take backup using ndb_mgm
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-cluster-backup-using-management-client.html

Like same whether we have steps to do the same on mysql work bench ? if you have please provide me the url to refer